# Show if $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous injective function, then it is an embedding.

Tags: general-topology

I know the definition of the embedding. I need to show that the inverse of restricted f is continuous but I couldn’t find a way to do it. Could you help with explicit details?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $f$ is continuous and injective then  it is strictly monotonic. This implies that $f^{-1}$ is also strictly monotonic. If $f^{-1}$ is not continuous the it has  a jump discontinuity at some point. If $a$ lies strictly between the left and right limits at a point of discontinuity look at the value $f(a)$ to get a  contradiction.

Comment: I am not sure if analytic arguments such as jump discontinuity would be appropriate. This is from my topology course.

Comment: @abeliangrape This result is specific to the real line and requires use of the ordering of real numbers.

Comment: The ordering is totally fine. We did learn the order topology. But I am pretty sure we can't use arguments such as jump discontinuity. I am not saying your answer is wrong; it is just that some tools are not available to us at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

$f[(0,1)]$ is a connected subset of $\Bbb R$ so of the form $[a,b), (a,b], (a,b)$ where $a$ or $b$ at "open ends" $)$ or $($ can be $\pm \infty$ too. This is a well-known characterisation of connected subsets of $\Bbb R$.
This implies the well-known intermediate value property of continuous functions on $(0,1)$ (or other connected subsets of $\Bbb R$): if $a < b$ in the domain and $z$ lies in the $(f(a),f(b))$ or $(f(b), f(a))$ (depending on the order of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ only one of the intervals is non-empty) then for some $x \in (a,b)$ we have $f(x)=z$.

If $f$ is moreover 1-1, this $x$ for $z$ is moreover unique and that implies that $[a,b)$ cannot happen as the image $f[(0,1)]$: if $x_0 \in (0,1)$ is such that $f(x_0)=a$ then pick $x_1,x_2$ in $(0,1)$ such that $0 < x_1 < x_0 < x_2 < 1$ and then $f(x_1) > a$ and $f(x_2)> a$ too and we'd have by the intermediate value property some $z \in (x_1,x_0)$ and some $z' \in (x_0,x_2)$ with the same $f$-value, contradicting 1-1-ness. Likewise $(a,b]$ is not an option. And so $f[(0,1)]$ is of the form $(a,b)$ and so open. Now a similar argument will show that $f$ must be strictly monotonic (increasing or decreasing) and this implies
that for all basic open $(c,d) \subseteq (0,1)$ $f[(c,d)]=(f(c),f(d))$ and thus open in $\Bbb R$ and an open, 1-1 continuous map is an embedding.

So the argument is basically connectedness and its consequences for an order topology.